# Cannot delete "Forgot Password?" on Sign in page. Seems completely unresponsive to code

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

## I'm expecting code to delete "Forgot Password?" hyperlink on sign in page

[Screenshot of deployed site (marked problem area in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMOIC.png)

I cannot delete "Forgot your Password?" link, the issue seems to be to do with django resorting to default code that I cannot locate. [Screenshot here of templates structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKuCW.png)

### My templates/allauth/account/login.html reads as this (debug code included.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign In" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 offset-md-2">
      <h3>{% trans "Sign In" %}</h3>

      <p>{% blocktrans %} $$$ This is debug text that DOES DISPLAY $$$$$$ Welcome back to the code|star blog. To leave a comment or like a post, please log in. If you
        have not created an account yet, then <a class="link" href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a>
        first.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 offset-md-2">
      <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
        {% endif %}
        <button class="btn btn-signup right" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This code uses django-allauth which has recently been updated. [Allauth documentation](https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/). The code may have been working before this package got updated.

### In templates/allauth/account/password_change.html I have commented out code - server appears unresponsive to this file.

```
{% extends "account/base_manage_password.html" %}
{% load allauth i18n %}
{% block head_title %}
    {% trans "Change Password" %}
{% endblock head_title %}
{% block content %}
    {% element h1 %}
        {% trans "Change Password" %}
    {% endelement %}
    {% url 'account_change_password' as action_url %}
    {% element form form=form method="post" action=action_url %}
        {% slot body %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% element fields form=form %}
            {% endelement %}
        {% endslot %}
        {% slot actions %}
            {% element button type="submit" %}
                {% trans "Change Password" %}
            {% endelement %}
            <!-- <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password? TESTHERE" %}</a> -->
        {% endslot %}
    {% endelement %}
{% endblock content %}
```

## Repo links

- See my full repo here: http://github.com/lmcrean/Project-4/
- See deployed site here: http://lmcrean-ittib-b97fbbd27fb0.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/

## So far I've tried ... lead to no change in deployed site.

- I've tried updating file structure to contain account within allauth
- I've updated settings to connect to allauth

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates", "allauth"),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

- I've tried deleting password_change.html
- login.html appears responsive (see debug text in earlier section)

Comment: It could be that you're changing the wrong template. You're checking the login page, but you've commented out the link on the template for the password change page (`password_change.html`).

Answer (score 0):

Reading your post it seems you are looking in the wrong html file. The page where you need to remove the html link is the log in html page, not the password change page.
I'm referring to your directory in production as you mentioned:
templates/account/login.html

Comment: Thank you, I have updated with login.html which I have been debugging